# Audiovisual content looses synchronization

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, webcam, opencv

I have a `.mp4` video file which came from an uncompressed `.avi` captured from a webcam through `emgu`. The emgu `videoWriter` is set to `30fps` even the real video `fps` is possibly lower, e.g., `29fps`. The command that is used to compress the `.avi` is:

**Compression command:**

```
fmpeg -i uncompresedvideo.avi -v quiet -stats -nostdin -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -preset veryfast -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1835k vid.mp4
```

**The video compression output is:**

```
ffmpeg version N-82060-g0cfd6cc Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 63.103 / 57. 63.103
  libavformat    57. 52.100 / 57. 52.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 64.100 /  6. 64.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\....\uncompresedvideo.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:02:50.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 110597 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x480, 110613 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[libx264 @ 0000000002636460] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0000000002636460] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0000000002636460] 264 - core 148 r2721 72d53ab - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=500 vbv_bufsize=1835 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\....\vid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.52.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.63.103 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 500000/0/0 buffer size: 1835000 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
```

In addition to this video recording I have a `.wav` file that came from a different device. I am trying to synchronize these to contents with the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i vid.mp4 -r 30 -i audio.wav -ar 16000 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -shortest output.mp4
```

**The synch command output is:**

```
ffmpeg version N-82060-g0cfd6cc Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 63.103 / 57. 63.103
  libavformat    57. 52.100 / 57. 52.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 64.100 /  6. 64.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audio.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.52.100
  Duration: 00:02:50.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 507 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 504 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from 'audio.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:52.29, bitrate: 512 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 16000 Hz, mono, flt, 512 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.52.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 504 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.63.103 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_f32le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 5108 fps=1316 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11735kB time=00:02:52.28 bitrate= 558.0kbits/s speed=44.4x
video:10486kB audio:1151kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.836344%
[aac @ 00000000026977c0] Qavg: 65093.531
```

I would like to mention that both audio and video have common start. While the audiovisual content has good synchronization at the beginning, the synchronization is lost at the end of the record. Could you please make a suggestion about what is happening?

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @slhck yes it was I made a refactoring and provide more details of the current situation. Thus, I thought it was better to start it from the begging giving a different perspective, hopping it will help others to understand more. I hope it is not a big problem.

Comment: @slhck I think I have the reason of my problem. The compressed video does not have constant `fps` through the entire recording. So may I ask if it is possible to transform a video of non constant fps to constant one with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Using the parameter `-r` option in compression command with an `fps` lower than that of the actual will it provide a constant frame rate `.mp4` video?

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't come across variable framerate video recently. Do you have a sample? Have you tried the `force-crf` option?

Comment: @slhck sorry for the delay. I have tested to compress the video with the `force-crf` option but did not work. May I ask if there is a possible option for the audio `.wav` which does not have always a constant sample rate?

Comment: @slhck thanks for the response. I would like to make a last try, so please let me ask the following. As it is described in the question, the real `fps` of the stream is different to the stored one via the `opencv`. Is it possible to change the `fps` during compression or afterwards? Also is that possible for the `.wav` file? Thanks again!

Comment: I wrote a more detailed response below. Again, seeing some samples would help in troubleshooting, but the way I understand your problem now, it seems to be impossible to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your input video already has wrong timestamps due to the way it was encoded. I understand that the original webcam video was outputting frames of variable length (i.e., a variable frame rate video), but an uncompressed AVI file can only store frames of *constant* length.

Thus, reading that AVI file (or any subsequently compressed MP4 file), ffmpeg will assume that it's a constant frame rate video. This leads to asynchronicity "building up" over time, since the timestamps in your AVI/MP4 have constant offsets. ffmpeg can't fix this for you, because the input timestamps are already incorrect. In other words, I assume that the `videoWriter` you refer to created a constant frame rate video from a variable frame rate one, creating incorrect timestamps. Without knowing when or how that frame rate changed, you cannot fix the timestamps.

Your only option would to re-generate the video stream from the webcam with a container that supports variable frame rate (such as MKV or MP4/MOV). Then, any subsequent conversion could synchronize the content with an audio stream. But since that webcam feed is probably live, there is no way to go back. Furthermore, I don't think that it's possible for OpenCV's `videoWriter` to output variable frame rate either (but I'm not an expert on this).

---

Note: It would be easier to fix this issue if your original video was encoded with a wrong *constant* frame rate. You could then force ffmpeg to assume another framerate for the input video, effectively removing the original timestamps and generating new ones, assuming a constant frame rate. For example, if your video conversion ended up creating a 30 fps video, but your original input was 29 fps, do this:

```
ffmpeg -r 29 -i <input> …
```